# Android thread memory Leak

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-activity, android-memory

I write to the shared preferences when Ever I get a certain broadcast msg from a service I have running. I want to know If this will cause a memory leak?
If so how can I fix it. I will be  required to run this code ever 20-25 min. Do the old thread Die?

```
if(Wifi_Connected)
{

    Thread thread2=  new Thread(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedData.edit();
                                  e.putInt("Value",1);
                                  e.commit();
                              }
                          });

                    thread2.start();

}
```

Comment: Why would you think it would cause a memory leak? What do you think might be leaking?

Comment: @JamesKPolk- I know that threads can cause memory leaks , that is why I am asking

Comment: I have a suggestion for you. Remove this thread completely and just write the code: `sharedData.edit().putInt("Value", 1).apply();` It will be much MUCH more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

No, it may cause some UI hiccups. Commit operation is very fast, so it will not hold outer class too long. But you better use apply() method which performs operation in background thread.
Generally speaking leaks appear when you hold reference to the 'big' objects like activity, and because of that it can not be destroyed.